# Update Google/Facebook buttons when adding login credentials

Tags: bug, design, login

The current [login screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login) shows the following:

[image]

Once logged in, [adding other login credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?ssrc=login) looks like this:

[image]

It's obvious that the Google/Facebook login icons need some update on the latter. Can this be done?